# NodeJS + miekal/request : How to abort a request?

Tags: node.js, request, streaming, pipe

I had been trying to abort a request for hours, can anyone help me please?

This is what I have:

```
app.get('/theUrl', function (req, resp) {

  var parser = new Transform();
  parser._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
    var _this = this;
    // Process data here
  }.on("error", function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });

  var theRequest = request({
    'method' : 'GET',
    'url': '/anotherUrl',
    'headers' : {
      "ACCEPT"  : "text/event-stream"
    }
  }, function (error, response, body){
    if (error) {
      //Throw error
    }
  }).pipe(parser).pipe(resp);

  req.on("close", function(){
    parser.end();
    theRequest.abort(); //Doesn't work
  });
});
```

As you can see its kinda a streaming proxy, so if clients cancels the request I catch it and need to close or abort the forwarding request (`theRequest`).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting nylen from https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/772#issuecomment-32480203 :

From the docs:

> pipe() returns the destination stream

so you are no longer working with a Request object. In this case you're calling abort() on a ServerResponse. Do this instead:

```
var theRequest = request({ ... });
theRequest.pipe(parser);
theRequest.abort();
```

And everything worked.